# attempting to get class names from a different package

Tags: java, package

Have got two projects javaapplication2 and javaapplication1. The same being their package names. In javaapplication2 ive imported javaapplication1 using

```
import javaapplication1.*;
```

i need to list all classses in the packeage. How to achieve this? I tried a simple code but it gets a null exception.

```
Package pck;
pck = Package.getPackage("javaapplication1");
System.out.println(pck.getClass());
```

Comment: What is Package. Is this your custom class ?

Comment: Have you checked that the javaaplication1 jar is on the classpath of javaaplication1?

Comment: Ive added javaapplication1 in the compile time library of javaapplication2. Am able to access its methods without javaapplication2's class extending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment on this question or to mark it as such, but it is a duplicate of:

[Getting all Classes from a Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810614/getting-all-classes-from-a-package)

There are many good answers listed on that question - for instance the top is looking for classes that implement ICommand, so to implement this all you need to do is remove:

```
if (ICommand.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
  commands.add((Class<ICommand>) cls);
}
```

from the for loop and you have what you want.

Comment: You are right but secondly i also need to retrieve the method names from corresponding classes. Dont think this way would be able to make me do that.

Comment: The http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html documentation for Java says you can use getDeclaredMethods() to retrieve a list of Method objects from a Class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the jar containing package javaapplication1 is not in classpath as

```
  Package.getPackage("javaapplication1");
```

is returning null for you.

**Also,**

You can have a look at the following link:

http://dzone.com/snippets/get-all-classes-within-package

or can explore the [Reflection library from Google](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) in order to get the required information, below is a sample code.

e.g.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("javaapplication1");
Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go throgh the object class API it is written as:

//Object API

---

getClass
public final Class getClass()Returns the runtime class of an object. That Class object is the object that is locked by static synchronized methods of the represented class.

Returns:
the object of type Class that represents the runtime class of the object.

---

It's clearly written as it represents the run time class of an object.
Suppose if you have class called as "Helloworld" in side "javaapplication1" package
create object of the class as:

Helloworld world=new Helloworld();
and then try to run as
System.out.println(wolrld.getClass());
It will return the class path of current object.