# Absolute Path from File in Package

Tags: java

Let's say I have a package: `com.example.resources` and inside it I have `picture.jpg` and `text.txt` - How can I use only the package path to identify the absolute filepath of `picture.jpg` and `text.txt`?

Is this correct?

```
File file1 = new File("/com/example/resources/picture.jpg");
file1.getAbsolutePath();

File file2 = new File("/com/example/resources/text.txt");
file2.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: "create 2 new File objects" Why?

Comment: You have to use a `ClassLoader` for that; what is more, you want `.getCanonicalPath()`.

Comment: Sorry, Really i cant get you.

Comment: The resources will likely be inside a jar file once the application is packaged and deployed. So there's no file path for these resources. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just take a look [getting-all-classes-from-a-package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810614/getting-all-classes-from-a-package) what will help you.

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm trying to reference those files within the application so that when I deploy the application to different systems I won't have to reconfigure the location of each resource "

You don't want to use a `File`, which will load from the file system of the local machine, you want to load through the class path, as that's how [**embedded resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) *should* be read. Use [`getClass().getResourceAsStream(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) for the text file and [`getClass().getReource(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) for the image

Your current path you're referencing looks like it *should* work, given the package name you've provided.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/2587435) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file) as some references.