# Java -jar ERROR: could not find or load main class

Tags: java, runtime, classloader, executable-jar

I am making a 2d game, which I have compiled into a .jar to test if it works.
When in run the jar file with `java -jar` command I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.grizeldi.splatoon.Main
```

I know that there are many solutions here on StackOveflow, but I have tried updating java, messing with -cp... Nothing worked so far.

Code: [github repo](https://github.com/grizeldi/Splatoon2D)

Help anyone?

EDIT1: I have my code on a USB stick, but I have tried moving it to C: and D: but nothing worked.
EDIT2: I have added the .jar on the github.

Comment: Yes my manifest is OK. Main class attribute is there.

Comment: What's the contents of the jar? (`unzip -l` or `jar -t`)

Comment: in root of jar are META-INF and com maps. In com then there are other packages.

Comment: Is your Main class in the jar in `com/grizeldi/splatoon/Main.class`?

Comment: Any other errors? Perhaps a stacktrace? Might be that a dependent class is missing. Maybe `BasicGame` from the `org.newdawn`? Add the jar containing that package to your classpath, then it probably works.

Comment: Some library classes might be missing, yes. Can that be the cause?

Comment: Added those libs into the same folder, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to update the Manifest with the classpath to the other jars:

```
Class-Path: lib.jar
```

An alternative is to add the contents of the jars your main jar depends on to your main jar, so you have only one jar file. Make sure you don't add the jars themselves to the main jar, as nested jars won't work.

When dealing with native libraries (`.so`, `.dll`), simply place these in the same directory as the jar. The downside of this is that you have multiple files.
In that case, it might be easiest to just add a startup script (`.sh`, `.bat`), specifying the classpath and the classname of Main, aswell as a `-Djava.library.path`.

There is also another way: extract the native library from the jar at runtime, save it to a temporary location, and load it explicitly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189776/load-native-library-from-class-path) for more info on that.

Comment: I had all jars in one folder (libs + splatoon2D.jar). Should that work?

Comment: -jar documentation says that when it is used, -cp is ignored I think

Comment: I don't think so; If I run `java` it says `... or java [-options] -jar jarfile`. If you want everything in your jar file, you'll have to unzip the libraries and add the contents to your jar.

Comment: Hope that this one works ;-) Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: it's ok ;). Is it ok if i just add lib jars to my splatoon jar? Because that didn't work.

Comment: No, nested jars won't work without custom code. You really have to unpack them first, and take care that your manifest won't be overwritten. If you use Maven to build, there's some tasks that can do all this automatically.

Comment: I'm using Intellij Idea's default jar creating thingy. I have tried adding all paths to classpath, but it again didn't work.

Comment: I think that the paths need to be relative to the jar that the manifest is in. Maybe Idea puts `lib/lib.jar` instead of `lib.jar` in the manifest? What's the contents of the manifest now, exactly?

Comment: I added all extracted libs to my jar and it kind of worked. Now it wants natives. Where should I put them?

Comment: TADA! I figured it out. Had to place natives in the same folder as my jar. Now if you edit your answer to something like "add all extracted libs to your jar", I'll accept it.