# EJB 3 Multiple Stateless Session Bean Implementations of the Same Interface

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish the following using EJB3.

I have the following interface:

```
interface DateParser {
    Date parseDate(String input);
    String getType();
}
```

Then I have several implementations of said interface that handle different formats based on the information given in the getType method. When my bean starts up it creates a Set of implementations of DateParser and when it needs to parse a date, it iterates over the set to see which one matches. If one matches it uses that one to parse the date. If none match, then it applies a default strategy. I would like to get away from instantiating these delegates because every time I add a new strategy it requires a code change in the bean making it a huge mess.

I would much prefer to have the container inject all of the implementations it finds at deployment. Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: If you are adding a new strategy, presumably THAT itself is a code change (a new strategy class)?  It sounds like you need the strategy classes register themselves with a factory and your main processor can simply ask the factory to provide the matching implementation.

Comment: Very true. I could simply register them with a factory. The goal is to then have them automatically register them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation of this interface should be regular classes, not beans. EJB are meant to be business services. Parsing date is IMHO a responsabiltiy that is too fine-grained for a bean.

> I would much prefer to have the container inject all of the
>   implementations it finds at deployment.

I don't think there is standard way to do that. I see only two options to dynamically fill the set with the instances:

1. Use an external configuration files with list of class names. Reach each class name and instantiate one instance reflectively ([Class.forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29), [Class.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)). Then add it to the set.
2. Iterate over all classes in the class path, identifiy those that are implementation of `DateParser`. Then instantiate it reflectively, and add it to the set. Note that iterating over loadable classes is kind of tricky, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498134/217862).

> it requires a code change in the bean making it a huge mess.

That should require a code change in a class, but not the bean itself. The bean should delegate the creation of the set, the identification of the parser, etc. to another class, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with your answer. My final solution was to implement a factory class that returned parsers based on a match. That isolated the changes involved in adding a new parser type to the factory class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, see this sample;

```
    @EJB(beanName = "yourSessionEJB")
    DateParser dateParser;
```

you can change other session bean name into **beanName** attribute. But one local interface used one session bean is recommended and not confused.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. In a strategy pattern you seek to have multiple implementations of the same interface then delegate to the proper one based on what you are trying to accomplish. Your example only injects a single interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the implementations of some interface, you can use @Any annotation with Instance interface.

Take a look at this: https://goo.gl/Kbn0bP